# struts 2 checkboxlist validation question

Tags: validation, struts2

I have struts 2 checkboxlist as followed:

```
<s:checkboxlist list="listOfOptions" name="someName" />
```

I would like to add validation to make sure that at least ONE of the checkboxes has been checked. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use JS to do that.

```
<sx:submit 
            id="button_submit"
            name="button_submit"
            onclick="return validateNotEmptyCheckbox();" />
```

And JS:

```
function validateNotEmptyCheckbox() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var fieldName = arguments[i];
        var atLeastOne = false;
        for (j = 0; j < checkboxes.length; j++) {
            if ((checkboxes[j].type == "checkbox" || checkboxes[j].type == "radio")
                    && checkboxes[j].name == fieldName
                    && checkboxes[j].checked == true)
                atLeastOne = true;
        }
        if (atLeastOne == false) {
            alert("Choose one!!!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Also for radio buttons, as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

I made an validation method on the action to whom the form is submitted.

deliveryTimesInputList is here the list of integer with the values from the checkboxlist.

```
@Override
public void validate() {

    if(deliveryTimesInputList == null || deliveryTimesInputList.isEmpty()){
        addFieldError("deliveryTimesInputList", "Du må velge minst et leveringstidspunkt for dette postnummeret");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for struts2 xml validation .The value of checkbox List is stored as a string.Hence,you can use requiredstring.

```
<field name="someName">
  <field-validator type="requiredstring">
     <message>You need to select at least one option</message>
   </field-validator>
  </field>
```